# Is it sensible to deliver a list of images as ByteArray and convert them to base64 client side?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, blob, filereader

Our backend team has decided that they would deliver images to the frontend as a ByteArray API call.

So currently these ByteArray image calls will be handled in Javascript client side as a Blob, and then are converted to base64.

```
let blob = new Blob([data], {type: this.getContentType(data)});
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob); // convert blob to base64
```

All in all, there could be around up to 100 images that would be converted like that on page load.

Somehow my gut feeling tells me that this is a bad idea, especially for performance. But maybe I'm mistaken? Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the goal ? Include everything in one query ? This should not really be a concern with HTTP2 and you defeat the standard cache.

Comment: We currently don't have HTTP2 available. In terms of performance I don't mean the number of requests needed, but the computing time needed in the browser to convert all these images.

Comment: Did you measure the increase in memory usage? Doing a non standard optimization should involve heavy measurements.